# Error plotting scikit-learn dataset training and test data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot the training and test data from a scikit-learn dataset.

```
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
plt.switch_backend('agg')

%matplotllib inline

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]
diabetes_X_train = diabetes_X[:-20]
diabetes_X_test = diabetes_X[-20:]
diabetes_y_train = np.matrix(diabetes.target[:-20]).T
diabetes_y_test = np.matrix(diabetes.target[-20:]).T

plt.scatter(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train,  color='black')
plt.scatter(diabetes_X_test, diabetes_y_test,  color='red')
```

but I have the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 422 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

I checked the shape of the matrices and the training data has (422,1) and the test data (20,1). What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) is expecting to plot two same-shaped datasets against each other. IF they aren't 1D, they will be flattened. It does not make sense to flatten `X` in a machine-learning problem.

Check the dimensions of `X_train` and `y_train`. You'll see that they aren't compatible. This is a 2D plot you're making, you can only plot one set of numbers against another. `X` is a matrix: every row is a bunch of numbers.

So you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.random.random((422, 1)), np.random.random((422, 1))
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

But you can't do this:

```
X, y = np.random.random((422, 10)), np.random.random((422, 1))
plt.scatter(X, y)
```

Which is essentially what you're trying to do. (I don't think you want to transpose `y` by the way.)

So this should work for you:

```
plt.scatter(diabetes_X_train[:, 0], diabetes_y_train)
```

But that only shows the relationship with one feature of `X`.

Assuming you're just trying to explore the data, I recommend checking out [`seaborn.pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). It's perfect for this sort of thing.

Comment: diabetes_X_train and diabetes_y_train just like diabetes_X_test and diabetes_y_test has the same shape size, respectively.

Comment: @Costa.Gustavo The things you plot together (e.g. `diabetes_X_train` and `diabetes_y_train` have to have the same shape _as each other_. Look at my examples again, and look at your arrays again. Try just plotting one pair of them (i.e. remove your second `plt.scatter()`. It doesn't work. You need to choose one column in `X` or try something like the `seaborn.pairplot` to make lots of plots.

Comment: @Costa.Gustavo I just added a bit to my answer to show that you should be able to plot a single column of `diabetes_X_train` with `diabetes_y_train`.